# openstack devstack installation stops with Connecting Dashboard Url

Tags: redhat, openstack, devstack

I was facing the below errors in OpenStack installation. Problem in connecting the dashboard URL.

Changed the url in **openrc** file by removing version like below http://100.1.201.102:5000/identity.

But still facing the same below issue. please let me know where exactly the error is being thrown .

```
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-0bb1-b2scc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created domain default
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-0bb1-b2scc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created project admin
DEBUG passlib.registry [req-412f0ceb-6b28-0bb1-b2scc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] registered 'sha512_crypt' handler: <class 'passlib.handlers.sha2_crypt.sha512_crypt'> register_crypt_handler /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/registry.py:284
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-0bb1-b2scc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created user admin
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-4bb1-b2cc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created role admin
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-4bb1-b2cc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Granted admin on admin to user admin.
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-4bb1-b2cc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created region RegionOne
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-4bb1-b2cc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created admin endpoint http://100.1.201.102/identity_v2_admin
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-4bb1-b2cc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created internal endpoint http://100.1.201.102/identity
INFO keystone.cmd.cli [req-412f0ceb-6b28-4bb1-b2cc-aae69e76ff7b - - - - -] Created public endpoint http://100.1.201.102/identity
2016-09-16 10:39:01.969 | +./stack.sh:main:1038                      cat
2016-09-16 10:39:01.998 | +./stack.sh:main:1053                      is_service_enabled tls-proxy
2016-09-16 10:39:02.055 | +functions-common:is_service_enabled:2078  return 1
2016-09-16 10:39:02.064 | +./stack.sh:main:1057                      source /devstack/userrc_early
2016-09-16 10:39:02.075 | ++userrc_early:source:4                     export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
2016-09-16 10:39:02.087 | ++userrc_early:source:4                     OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
2016-09-16 10:39:02.098 | ++userrc_early:source:5                     export OS_AUTH_URL=http://100.1.201.102/identity_v2_admin
2016-09-16 10:39:02.109 | ++userrc_early:source:5                     OS_AUTH_URL=http://100.1.201.102/identity_v2_admin
2016-09-16 10:39:02.121 | ++userrc_early:source:6                     export OS_USERNAME=admin
2016-09-16 10:39:02.133 | ++userrc_early:source:6                     OS_USERNAME=admin
2016-09-16 10:39:02.144 | ++userrc_early:source:8                     export OS_PASSWORD=secret
2016-09-16 10:39:02.156 | ++userrc_early:source:8                     OS_PASSWORD=secret
2016-09-16 10:39:02.168 | ++userrc_early:source:9                     export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
2016-09-16 10:39:02.181 | ++userrc_early:source:9                     OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
2016-09-16 10:39:02.192 | ++userrc_early:source:11                    export OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
2016-09-16 10:39:02.204 | ++userrc_early:source:11                    OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
2016-09-16 10:39:02.214 | +./stack.sh:main:1059                      create_keystone_accounts
2016-09-16 10:39:02.223 | +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:384  local admin_project
2016-09-16 10:39:02.235 | ++lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:385  openstack project show admin -f value -c id
2016-09-16 10:40:19.898 | Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
2016-09-16 10:40:19.898 | Could not determine a suitable URL for the plugin
2016-09-16 10:40:19.981 | +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:385  admin_project=
2016-09-16 10:40:19.992 | +lib/keystone:create_keystone_accounts:1   exit_trap
2016-09-16 10:40:20.003 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  local r=1
2016-09-16 10:40:20.014 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs -p
2016-09-16 10:40:20.025 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs=
2016-09-16 10:40:20.036 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  [[ -n '' ]]
2016-09-16 10:40:20.047 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  kill_spinner
2016-09-16 10:40:20.059 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:383               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2016-09-16 10:40:20.069 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2016-09-16 10:40:20.080 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  echo 'Error on exit'
2016-09-16 10:40:20.080 | Error on exit
2016-09-16 10:40:20.093 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  generate-subunit 1474021993 427 fail
2016-09-16 10:40:20.697 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:502                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2016-09-16 10:40:20.703 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:505                  devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2016-09-16 10:40:21.394 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  exit 1
```

Comment: Which guides were you following? I haven't seen anything that actually uses 'identity' as the version. It should be looking for "http://[IP]:5000/v2.0" or "http://[IP]:5000/v3" depending on which version you want to use. 2.0 has tenants/older names, while 3 adds domains/groups/projects.

Comment: @LazyGuy: This error occurs when there is incompatibility between versions of devstack and openstack services. Which version of devstack ? And also mention the `localrc` file ?